# Wire sizes, difference between "-" vs "/"

Tags: wire, awg, wire-size

Is there a difference between 10/2 AWG and 10-2 in wire sizes? Why is there sometimes used a slash and other times used a dash? Googled this but didn't find anything.

Comment: The '-' and '/' are just separators between the wire gauge (1st number) and number of conductors (2nd number). It makes no difference.

Comment: Please link to the data sheets of the cables that have these somewhat contradictory definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of a hyphen versus forward slash is often preference with prevalence varying somewhat by region or country.

However, be aware that sometimes the slash notation is used for multiples of 0 gauge wire. For example, `000` gauge is sometimes written as 3/0 (per [American wire gauge entry at Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Nomenclature_and_abbreviations_in_electrical_distribution).

Comment: If 000 = 3/0 then what is the difference between 000 here and 3/0?  They list a 3/0 AWG and a 000 AWG separately: https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Comment: I see the 000 but no 3/0 at the link you provided @RobertC

Comment: @relayman357 I figured 1, 2, 3, etc on that chart would be 1/0 AWG, 2/0 AWG, 3/0 AWG. If they are not, what sizes are they?

Comment: Context is important. If you see `3/0` it is _probably_ #000 (three-aught), but it _could_ be three conductors of #0. If you see `10/2`, it is two conductors of #10. As far as I know, only #0 and above (#00, #000, etc.) uses the slash notation as a shorthand for "number of zeroes".

Comment: @RobertC The 0, 1, 2, and 3 in that chart are all standard wire gauges. For wire thicker than 0 gauge, it starts adding zeroes: 0 is thicker than 1, and 00 is thicker than 0. As to _why_ AWG uses this silly convention, one would have to consult the history books.